# hide show legend in scatter highcharter

Tags: r, r-highcharter

How could I hide and show the legend?
It is necessary to improve the display of the graph because it incorporates many elements. Initially it should be hidden, but a button should allow the user to hide or show the legend.

Here you have the R code, as well as the dataframe to reproduce the graph.

```
hc <- dfo %>%
 hchart(
  type = "scatter",
  hcaes(
   x = dfo$`Esfuerzo`,
   y = dfo$`Umbral`,
   size = dfo$`Relevancia` * 100,
   group = dfo$`Municipio`
   ),
  tooltip = list(
   valueDecimals = 2,
   valueSuffix = " %"
  ),
  dataLabels = list(
   enabled=TRUE, 
   format='{y:.2f}',
   style = list(fontSize = "16px"),
   color = "#666666"
  )
 ) %>%
 hc_title(
  text = "Compromiso",
  style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "28px")
 ) %>%
 hc_subtitle(
  text = "",
  align = "center",
  style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "18px")
 ) %>%
 hc_xAxis(
  labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "14px")),
  title = list(
   text = "Esfuerzo",
   style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "20px")
  ),
  plotLines = list(
   list(label = list(text = ""),
        color = "#FF4040",
        width = 3,
        value = median(dfo$`Esfuerzo`)
   )
  )
 ) %>% 
 hc_yAxis(
  labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "14px")),
  title = list(
   text = "% Umbral", 
   style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "20px")
  ),
  plotLines = list(
   list(label = list(text = ""),
        color = "#FF4040",
        width = 3,
        value = median(dfo$`Umbral`)
   )
  )
 ) %>%
 hc_exporting (
  enabled = TRUE
 ) %>%
 hc_add_theme(
  hc_theme_tufte()
 )
hc
```

```
structure(list(Código = c("02003", "03014", "04013", "05019", 
"06015", "07040", "08019", "09059", "10037", "11012", "12040", 
"13034", "14021", "15030", "16078", "17079", "18087", "19130", 
"21041", "22125", "23050", "24089", "25120", "26089", "27028", 
"28079", "29067", "30030", "32054", "33044", "34120", "35016", 
"36038", "37274", "38038", "39075", "40194", "41091", "42173", 
"43148", "44216", "45168", "46250", "47186", "49275", "50297", 
"51001", "52001"), Municipio = c("Albacete", "Alicante/Alacant", 
"Almería", "Ávila", "Badajoz", "Palma", "Barcelona", "Burgos", 
"Cáceres", "Cádiz", "Castellón de la Plana/Castelló de la Plana", 
"Ciudad Real", "Córdoba", "Coruña (A)", "Cuenca", "Girona", "Granada", 
"Guadalajara", "Huelva", "Huesca", "Jaén", "León", "Lleida", 
"Logroño", "Lugo", "Madrid", "Málaga", "Murcia", "Ourense", "Oviedo", 
"Palencia", "Palmas de Gran Canaria (Las)", "Pontevedra", "Salamanca", 
"Santa Cruz de Tenerife", "Santander", "Segovia", "Sevilla", 
"Soria", "Tarragona", "Teruel", "Toledo", "Valencia", "Valladolid", 
"Zamora", "Zaragoza", "Ceuta", "Melilla"), Esfuerzo = c(66.255518296917, 
55.4505971732305, 67.3396882117212, 159.444527678894, 39.9208624778303, 
75.6407281816124, 191.885593614053, 66.4060669160645, 41.5696869168135, 
131.928027073733, 70.8156033699513, 63.3576317305502, 99.9022751874716, 
92.1737310681322, 38.5831640425687, 91.7932459374022, 108.74338544486, 
42.8257587497772, 67.209950935465, 52.5816548264175, 102.778140636216, 
81.7958449372392, 87.2101693767431, 82.8515582299525, 64.2431323026685, 
116.244125268106, 95.4495291756444, 57.9232964761993, 74.9121459540308, 
75.0079722742974, 72.345751914009, 131.407698477426, 37.4719669533452, 
70.9266085324988, 119.707963542996, 56.4080210059843, 76.5130914290131, 
102.864800169414, 155.927878655384, 96.0587342879086, 57.0368704204712, 
43.3062216835242, 83.7300653585645, 68.8468635870744, 57.9772431037523, 
112.835558277614, 189.188525288669, 431.185251161171), Relevancia = c(0.0779438999416286, 
0.075567624299619, 0.0830963177638657, 0.181216919752304, 0.0645578573307309, 
0.0694739535415282, 0.11238222267336, 0.0591312044270579, 0.0549171188507039, 
0.107335017649502, 0.0672279971174195, 0.0622048291208239, 0.106492447121433, 
0.0989219226252717, 0.0434299324062133, 0.080124826578867, 0.0923126527122762, 
0.055862728725791, 0.0816954005957221, 0.0569671724881646, 0.0902113572693082, 
0.0760249770659709, 0.0786282259767798, 0.0920644595378507, 0.0827523660072055, 
0.0869155856787086, 0.0892429670963684, 0.0705333155849015, 0.0852996555846074, 
0.069397881679441, 0.0843127745258698, 0.151586054295292, 0.0464492613233081, 
0.0720415327066066, 0.119890097237675, 0.0503879549782981, 0.0624360563921389, 
0.0965284452003263, 0.159516287787606, 0.0739061270776166, 0.0694730992371514, 
0.0410407530273502, 0.0855901086450992, 0.0787793734678359, 0.0688139147586614, 
0.102143947795215, 0.0634263210053491, 0.149047512460091), Umbral = c(21, 
28.8, 30.3, 19.2, 24.4, 16.8, 15.4, 12.8, 19.4, 20.3, 20.7, 18.6, 
24.6, 16.5, 19.4, 18.2, 24.8, 16.8, 26.5, 16.2, 20.5, 16.9, 21.4, 
16.5, 19.3, 17.3, 27.9, 24, 19.8, 16.7, 15.1, 25.6, 19.9, 20.5, 
27, 17.8, 18.2, 24.9, 13.6, 19.3, 13.1, 14.5, 21.6, 15.1, 20.4, 
14.9, 34.8, 37)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -48L
))
```

**At the moment, I have advanced only a little, I have added this code but without reaching the solution**

```
 hc_legend (
  enabled = TRUE
 ) %>%
 hc_exporting (
  buttons = list(
   customButton = list(
    text = 'Ocultar Legenda',
    onclick = JS("function() {

     var chart = this;
     chart.legend.update({enabled: false});

     //chart.series[0].update({visible: false})

     alert(chart.legend);
     alert(\"Has presionado el botón\");

    }")
   ),
   customButton = list(
    text = 'Mostrar Legenda',
    onclick = JS("function() {

     var chart = this;
     chart.legend.update({enabled: true});

     //chart.series[0].update({visible: false})

     alert(chart.legend);
     alert(\"Has presionado el botón\");

    }")
   )
  ),
  enabled = TRUE
 ) %>%
```

I am starting with highcharter and I need help.
I can't solve this big problem for me.
Kind regards.

Comment: I have updated the question with the progress ...

Answer (score 2):

Passing the object to `hc_legend` seemed to hide the legend. In other words, just tack on `%>% hc_legend(element_blank)` and it disappears. I am not sure about adding a button though. I think you would need to be inside a Shiny application or something similar, and make this reactive code with the last line not present/present depending on the setting and link to another button. Code for hiding the legend:

```
hc <- dfo %>%
  hchart(
    type = "scatter",
    hcaes(
      x = dfo$`Esfuerzo`,
      y = dfo$`Umbral`,
      size = dfo$`Relevancia` * 100,
      group = dfo$`Municipio`
    ),
    tooltip = list(
      valueDecimals = 2,
      valueSuffix = " %"
    ),
    dataLabels = list(
      enabled=TRUE, 
      format='{y:.2f}',
      style = list(fontSize = "16px"),
      color = "#666666"
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_title(
    text = "Compromiso",
    style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "28px")
  ) %>%
  hc_subtitle(
    text = "",
    align = "center",
    style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "18px")
  ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(
    labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "14px")),
    title = list(
      text = "Esfuerzo",
      style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "20px")
    ),
    plotLines = list(
      list(label = list(text = ""),
           color = "#FF4040",
           width = 3,
           value = median(dfo$`Esfuerzo`)
      )
    )
  ) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(
    labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "14px")),
    title = list(
      text = "% Umbral", 
      style = list(fontWeight = "bold", fontSize = "20px")
    ),
    plotLines = list(
      list(label = list(text = ""),
           color = "#FF4040",
           width = 3,
           value = median(dfo$`Umbral`)
      )
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_exporting (
    enabled = TRUE
  ) %>%
  hc_add_theme(
    hc_theme_tufte()
  ) %>% 
  hc_legend(element_blank())
hc
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: My problem is not initially showing or hiding the chart legend, but after the chart is loaded, hiding the legend if it was initially shown, or showing it if it was initially hidden.